# VisualBrush color not changing when selected

Tags: wpf

I've created a VisualBrush in WPF to give me a wavy underline for a character.

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="WavyBrush">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Path Data="M 0,2 L 2,0 4,2 6,0 8,2 10,0 12,2" Stroke="Black" />
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

It works great except when I put the result in a DataGrid and select the row. If an unselected row has black text with white background and selecting the row turns the text white, (and the background blue or some other color) my VisualBrush with Stroke="Black" stays black, doesn't go white and looks confusing.

Is there a way to get the brush to act like color of text?

Comment: Using `VisualBrush` this way is not what it's designed for. If you want to turn a `Path`'s Data to some `Brush`, you can use just `DrawingBrush`, then you can just use the `Path`'s Data for `PathGeometry`.

Comment: The comment fixed my problem perfectly. Do you want to put it as an answer?

Comment: nice to know you could easily fix the issue when using `DrawingBrush` instead. I just suggested to use it because it's more convenient, however using the `VisualBrush` should not be a problem (you can still make it work using it). I'm not very sure about how it is close to your question, I mean you had to almost solve it yourself so it's better not to add an answer, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is interested, the DrawingBrush acts like text and changes color when selected.

```
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="TextBoxWavyBrush">
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <DrawingGroup.Children>
                    <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M 0,2 L 2,0 4,2 6,0 8,2 10,0 12,2">
                        <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <Pen Thickness="1" StartLineCap="Round" EndLineCap="Round" LineJoin="Round" Brush="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=Foreground}"/>
                        </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                    </GeometryDrawing>
                </DrawingGroup.Children>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataTrigger` to change the color of the brush when the row is selected. The code uses `ListBox` but you could easily adapt it to use `DataGrid`.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <VisualBrush x:Key="WavyBrush">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Path Data="M 0,2 L 2,0 4,2 6,0 8,2 10,0 12,2" Stroke="Black" />
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
    <VisualBrush x:Key="whiteWavyBrush">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Path Data="M 0,2 L 2,0 4,2 6,0 8,2 10,0 12,2" Stroke="White" />
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="50" Width="350">
                    <Border x:Name="border" Width="350" Height="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource WavyBrush}">
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource whiteWavyBrush}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: that's fine, I guess the framework handles `DrawingBrush` differently, it auto reverse the drawing's color (to hightlight) when the drawing is selected; On the other hand, `VisualBrush` is relatively primitive.